# How do I start windows 7 explorer in desktop mode when an application is runnig as shell?

Tags: c#, .net, desktop, explorer

I wrote an application for a parking garage that has to be "fool proof"...
One of the things I'm doing is that I start the application as shell instead of the explorer. (HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell set to my application).

Inside this application I implemented a little service dialog, well protected from the user, that allows me to start e.g. the explorer.
What I'd need now is a way to start the explorer as desktop.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Nothing is "fool proof". And are you asking how to run `explorer.exe` from your program?

Comment: my app is as good as fool proof, I need the desktop just for maintenance sometimes (SQL Server Magagement Studio). It's not a problem to start explorer.exe, but then it's in file manager mode, not in desktop mode, that's my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this discussion on Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/51e7090e-f367-4d0a-b737-b2feacf9b5ae/how-to-start-windows-shell-explorerexe-when-custom-shell-is-configured) it's not possible.

> It is NOT possible to set explorer as shell without designating it as shell in the registry key.
>
> Keeping explorer as shell in the registry, but killing explorer.exe and launching your shell work as an option for you?
>
> I dont see any other clean way around.

One user posted a possible solution though.

> change HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell to "explorer.exe"
>
> run "userinit.exe"
>
> change HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell back to your custom shell

```
My Code (autoit)
RegWrite('HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon','Shell',"REG_SZ",'Explorer.exe')
Run('userinit.exe')
ProcessWait('explorer.exe')
RegWrite('HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon','Shell',"REG_SZ",@ScriptFullPath)
```

I've had to do a similar thing in the past, with a mobile device running in kiosk mode. For debugging purposes on-site I did this:

- On application startup, check for a config setting like `debug = true`. If so, boot explorer.exe instead.
- Connect to the device, set this setting and reboot if you want to debug.

Comment: killing a process should be the last thing one should do, but as a daily routine? I don't like that :) But the other solution seems quite good, I'll try that later. The thing is that I need the shell maybe 2 times a year, so the desktop is the exception. Killing the explorer at least daily seems a bit too risky.

Comment: I've had a similar "issue" in the past, where I needed the desktop on a mobile device in kiosk mode. I'll add that solution to my answer.

Comment: I decided to try this now, even thought I should already be at the customers site :) Since this could only have broken my maintenance code but not the application, thorough testing wasn't that important. What shall I say? 5 minutes of development time 5 minutes testing, 3 minutes installing the update on the customers pc. It just works, plain and simple :) THANKS Stijn!